# Create 2 buttons on the same x axis in jFrame

Tags: java, swing, layout, layout-manager

My java code below features a image and a button below I just want to add another button that is on the same x axis as the one the current button is on. I don't know how to do that. I thought I tried to manipulate abc.weightx and change it and it had no effect. I have included a pic of what I am trying to do below.

[image]

```
    import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
   import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.net.URL;
   import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
    import javax.swing.JButton;
  import javax.swing.JFrame;
  import javax.swing.JLabel;

    class Main extends JFrame {

public static void main(String[] args0) {

    try {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
        gbc.weightx = 0.5;
        gbc.weighty = 0.4;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;

        URL url = new URL("http://www.digitalphotoartistry.com/rose1.jpg");
        ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon(url);
        JLabel imageLabel = new JLabel(image);
        frame.add(imageLabel, gbc);

        gbc.weightx = 0.9;
        gbc.weighty = 0.1;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;







        JButton b = new JButton("Click Here");
        frame.add(b, gbc);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Put the buttons in a centered flow layout. Put the flow layout in the page end of a border layout.

Comment: I am new to java don't know how to that? Can you show me in code.I really appreciate your help.

Comment: *"Can you show me in code"* SO is not a code generation service. If you make an attempt to implement the advice & fail, [edit] to post a [mre] and I will have a further look.

Answer (score 1):

You're not setting the `gridx` and `gridy` from your `GridBagConstraint` so they probably won't appear where you want them to.

I'd suggest to follow [@AndrewThompson's advice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59814838/1098603) and go for a `BorderLayout` with your main panel in the `BorderLayout.CENTER` position, and your buttons in a separate `JPanel` with the default `FlowLayout`, that you'd put in the `BorderLayout.SOUTH` position.

If you want to stick with `GridBagLayout`:

- Main panel: `gridx=0` `gridy=0` `gridwidth=2` `weightx=1` `weighty=1`
- Left button: `gridx=0` `gridy=1`
- Right button: `gridx=1` `gridy=1`

I'm not posting code because you'll learn a lot more if you try it all yourself.